# Contrast color for colormap

Tags: matlab, colors, background-color, matlab-figure, contrast

I have a variety of image plots where I use different [colormaps](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/colors-1.html) for each one. I would like to plot colored lines on these graphs that are noticeable against the background/have a large contrast to the colors used in the colormap.

**Is there a list of/method to calculate the best visual contrast colors for the color maps?**

If an answer only exists for particular color maps: I mainly use `colormap(jet)` and the 2015 default colormap, which I believe is `colormap(parula)`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer is kind of subjective; at one extreme, black and white offer, obviously, the best contrast. At the other, red and green may look the same to a color-blind person. Relative brightness between foreground and background is also important for contrast. I think you have two approaches: the simplest might be that opposite ends of the colormap tend to have good contrast. A more elaborate approach is to generate a list of `[foreground, background]` combinations that in your judgement provide good contrast. You can look at a color-wheel to have a good idea, but trial and error or looking at guidelines for illustrators may give you hints.

Comment: thanks for your answer! i'm surprised that the notion of contrast of color can not be defined in a quantitative way. And even if it is subjective to some extent, surely some person doing automatic arts generation has made a list?

Comment: There are many such palettes, especially for web-design. An example is [here](http://colorsafe.co/).